# Table with id don't show borders around td and tr on css

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with id #search_form

When I write this

```
table#search_form, tr#search_form, td#search_form, th#search_form {
    height: 2em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

It only shows border around the table, not around tr, td or th.

But when I write this:

```
table, tr, td {
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

It shows border in any table around tr, td too. But I want borders only on table with specific id.

Why doesn't it work?

I tried to make separate blocks in css like tr#search_form { .. } but it doesn't work either.

I tried to remove comma sign, remmove the id tag but it doesn't work.

Why it behaves that way?

Here's the HTML table:

```
<table id="search_form">
          <form method = "get">
              <tr>
          <th>
              <label>Search in file database </label>
              <br><input type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search" maxlength="45">
             <br><button type="submit" name="search" value="search">Search</button>
          </th>
          <td>
                  <label for="start">Start date range:</label>
                  <br><input type="date" id="from date" name="from-date"
                             value=""
                             min="2020-03-01" max="">
              <br><label for="end">End date range:</label>
              <br><input type="date" id="to date" name="to-date"
                         value=""
                         min="2020-03-01" max="">
          </td>
                  <td>
                  </td>
          </form>
          <form method = "get">
              <th>
                  <label>Tags search</label>
                  <br><input type="text" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="tag1,tag2,tag3">
                  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
                  <script src="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
                  <br><button type="submit" name="search" value="tagssearch">Search</button>
              </th>
              <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="andcondition" value="1">
              Check if you want each file to include all tags (AND condition)
              </td>
              </tr>
          </form>
      </table>
```

Comment: What does the html look like? Just your tables should have the id="search_form". Also the convention for html is kebab-case. So not search_form but search-form.

Comment: Another question, could you clarify what it is you are trying to do again. This code seems to work. There is a border around the table, I have tried on jsbin.

Comment: @jhamPac I want border around all cells, not just one around the whole table.

Comment: oh ok, let me update my answer

Comment: did the updated answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code places a border only on tables with an id of search_form and also a border around th and td children:

```
#search_form {
   height: 2em;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   border: 10px solid black;
}

#search_form th {
  border: solid 5px black
}

#search_form td {
  border: solid 5px black
}
```

Small suggestion I would kebab-case the id name because that is the convention for HTML.

Then your HTML could be:

```
<table id="search-form">
   ...
</table>
```

Comment: You will have to adjust the border thickness but this should get you started on what you need @Coder88